# can I change the color of log data in winston?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, winston, bunyan

I happened to use bunyan to log the the data . I wanted the logs be printed with appropriate colors like errors in red , debug yellow .. etc; unfortunately I couldn't find anyways to do that . And now I would like to know if its possible with winston. Can I change the color of log data in winston ?

here is the code that I executed .

```
  var logger = require("winston-color");
  var winston = require('winston');  
  var util    = require('util');

  var logFilename = __dirname + '/logfile.log';

  var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ 
      filename: 'logfile.log',
      timestamp:true 
     }),
      new (winston.transports.File)({
      name: 'error-log',
      filename: 'error.log',
      level: 'error'
      }),

     new (winston.transports.File)({
     name: 'info-log',
     filename: 'info.log',
     level: 'info'
     }),
    ]
  });
  logger.info('Hello Winston info!');
  logger.debug('Hello Winston debug!');
  logger.warn('Hello Winston warn!');
  logger.info('Hello again distributed logs'); 
  logger.error('error1');
  logger.error('error2');
```

the output screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsuAI.png)

working code's output here [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6CmW.png)

Comment: There's [winston-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-color) package which does the job?

Comment: didn't work !! it shows the out put in plain white !

Comment: By looking at the code, it feels like you've redefined `logger` back to default one?

Comment: redefining logger ? can you please make me clear on it ? If observed output screen shot it didn't print debug statement . How can I get out of it ?

Comment: I understood what the problem was ! but this also works the same way as bunyan . It only shows the log levels in colors but not the log data .

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can. You can use the following code that I am using in my project.

**logger/WinstonPlugin.js**

```
/* jslint node: true */
/* jshint esversion: 6 */

'use strict';
const Winston = require('winston');
const logLevel = 'debug';

var logger;

(function createLogger() {

    logger = new(Winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new(Winston.transports.Console)({
                level: logLevel,
                colorize: true,
                timestamp: function () {
                    return (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
                },
                prettyPrint: true
            })
        ]
    });

    Winston.addColors({
        error: 'red',
        warn: 'yellow',
        info: 'cyan',
        debug: 'green'
    });
})();

module.exports = logger;
```

And anytime you needed the Winston in any your code file. You can access like below:

```
const Winston = require('logger/WinstonPlugin');
Winston.info('This is a info statement');
Winston.debug('This is a debug statement');
Winston.warn('This is a warning statement');
Winston.error('This is a error statement');
```

and you will see the colored output in the console.

Answer (score 12):

If you look for a custom color schema you can write your own transporter like this

```js
import winston from "winston";
import Transport from "winston-transport";

const Colors = {
    info: "\x1b[36m",
    error: "\x1b[31m",
    warn: "\x1b[33m",
    verbose: "\x1b[43m",
};

class SimpleConsoleTransport extends Transport {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    log = (info, callback) => {
        const { level, message, stack } = info;
        console.log(
                `${Colors[level]}${level}\t${message}\x1b[0m`,
                stack ? "\n" + stack : ""
            )
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    };
}
```

then config your winston instance this way:

```js
winston.configure({
            transports: [new SimpleConsoleTransport()],
        });
```

these are the whole list of colors you can use:

```
Reset = "\x1b[0m"
Bright = "\x1b[1m"
Dim = "\x1b[2m"
Underscore = "\x1b[4m"
Blink = "\x1b[5m"
Reverse = "\x1b[7m"
Hidden = "\x1b[8m"

FgBlack = "\x1b[30m"
FgRed = "\x1b[31m"
FgGreen = "\x1b[32m"
FgYellow = "\x1b[33m"
FgBlue = "\x1b[34m"
FgMagenta = "\x1b[35m"
FgCyan = "\x1b[36m"
FgWhite = "\x1b[37m"

BgBlack = "\x1b[40m"
BgRed = "\x1b[41m"
BgGreen = "\x1b[42m"
BgYellow = "\x1b[43m"
BgBlue = "\x1b[44m"
BgMagenta = "\x1b[45m"
BgCyan = "\x1b[46m"
BgWhite = "\x1b[47m"
```

Answer (score 6):

I followed [this](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1135#issuecomment-347581344) answer and got it working with colors

```
new winston.transports.Console({
  format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.colorize(),
            winston.format.simple()
          )
});
```

Answer (score 3):

## Emoji

You can use colors for text as others mentioned in their answers.

But you can use **emojis** instead! for example, you can use`⚠️` for warning messages and  for error messages. (Even without the logger! But you can also wrap it inside the logger for access control purpose)

Or simply use these notebooks as a color:

```js
console.log(': error message');
console.log(': warning message');
console.log(': ok status message');
console.log(': action message');
console.log(': canceled status message');
console.log(': Or anything you like and want to recognize immediately by color');
```

#### Bonus:

This method also helps you to quickly scan and find logs **directly in the source code**.

Also, it does not depend on any framework and you can use it anywhere freely.

<sub>But Linux default emoji font is not colorful by default and you may want to make them colorful, first.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

All might be right but i have one simple solution for that

create a file called `winston.js` and put below code

```
const winston = require('winston');
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.colorize(),
                winston.format.simple()
            )
        })
    ]
});
global.logger = logger;
```

Now import this file to any file you want (Probably index.js).

```
require('./config/winston');
logger.error("Oops, It's Error");
logger.info("This is info Msg");
logger.warn("Something went wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this. But according to this you use color for logs.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#using-custom-logging-levels)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response . I tried it too . But I need the entire log data of certain level be of a color .

Answer (score 0):

I've combined some solutions:

```js
import { createLogger, format, transports, addColors } from 'winston';
const { combine, colorize, label, timestamp, printf } = format;

interface LogInfo {
    level: string;
    message: string;
    label?: string;
    timestamp?: string;
}

export const LOGGER_MSG_ICONS = {
  error: "",
  warn: "",
  info: "",
  unknown: "",
};

export const LOGGER_MSG_COLORS = {
  error: "bold red",
  warn: "italic yellow",
  info: "bold blue",
}

const customFormat = format.combine(
    colorize({ all: true }),
    label({ label: '[LOGGER]' }),
    timestamp({ format: 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' }),
    printf((info: LogInfo) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-control-regex
        const cleanLevel = info.level.replace(/\u001b\[.*?m/g, '');
        const pre = MSG_PREFIXES[cleanLevel as keyof typeof MSG_PREFIXES] || '';

        return ` ${pre}${info.label} ${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
    })
);

addColors(MSG_COLORS);

const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    transports: [new transports.Console({ format: combine(customFormat) })],
});
```

using:

```js
    logger.info(`Listening on port ${port}`);
    logger.warn(`Lorem ipsum`);
    logger.error(`dolor sit amet`);
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Tried your fix; Winston doesn't pay attention to any of the color settings.